# cannot install visual studio 2010 64 bit prerequites

Tags: visual-studio-2010

cannot able to install the visual studio 2010. Please refer the attached image.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

**You Can Download ISO File From Here and try to Reinstall it:**

http://allpcworld.com/download-visual-studio-2010-express-free/